# Using part of date in CAML query

Tags: list-view, caml-query, list-definition

I want to create new view for my list. The list contains a column called `Year`, which is a number and contains, as name suggests, year. Eg.:

```
2012
2011
2010
2009
```

I would like create a view, where I would display only last 3 years. The `<Query>` element of my List Definition is:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="Year" />
      <Value Type="Number"> ???? </Value>
    </Geq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

And it gets tricky here. **How to write a condition, that a number should be greater that current year minus 3?** I thought it would work like in UI, so I could use:

```
YEAR([Today])-3
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can you use the OffsetDays attribute for this? (all depends on how exact the 3 years should be) as there is no way you can do leap years this way.
Here is how do it using days in case.

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="Year" />
         <Today OffsetDays="-1" /> //amount of days to subtract
    </Geq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was to create additional calculated column that returns either **"yes"** or **"no"** values. In your case the formula would be similar to:

```
=IF([Year]>=TEXT(YEAR([Today])-3,"0"),"Yes","No")
```

In order to be able to use [Today] in the formula you need to create a single line of text field called **"Today"**. After your calculated column is created remove the **"Today"** column (here is the original [post](http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/) for the process).

Once you have the calculated column created, your query would look similar to this:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Geq>
      <FieldRef Name="<Calc Field Here>" Type="Choice"/>
        <Value Type="Choice">Yes</Value>
    </Geq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```